# What is the impact if I declare the maximum size of a uniform buffer in vulkan shader?

Tags: graphics, glsl, game-development, vulkan

For example, the value of `maxUniformBufferRange` is 65536 on my GPU.
(I'm not sure if it is the max size limit of the uniform buffer or just update size limit.)

If I declare a uniform buffer in shader like:

```
layout (binding = 1) uniform UBO
{
    uint Source[65536/4];
};
```

But in vulkan api side I only use part of it, say 64 bytes.
Will there be any bad impact on this?

Comment: With SSBOs you can have a flexible array member at the end (`uint Source[];`) so you aren't writing out the size in the shader. Any reason you aren't using an SSBO?

Comment: Implementation dependent.

Comment: @Andrea It seems GPUs have dedicated memory for UBOs (especially for Nvidia) thus it's faster than SSBO, but I'm not sure. What's your opinion on this?

Comment: That may be true, not all vendors will implement UBOs and SSBOs the same way.